# Error "write(stdout): Broken pipe" when using GNU netcat with named pipe

Tags: bash, pipe, sh, fifo, netcat

I have a simple shell script `sv` that responds to HTTP requests with a short message:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

echo_crlf() {
        printf '%s\r\n' "$@"
}

respond() {
        body='Hello world!'
        echo_crlf 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK'
        echo_crlf 'Connection: close'
        echo_crlf "Content-Length: $(echo "$body" | wc -c)"
        echo_crlf 'Content-Type: text/plain'
        echo_crlf
        echo "$body"
}

mkfifo tube
respond < tube | netcat -l -p 8888 > tube
rm tube
```

When I start the script and send a request,
everything looks right on the client side:

```
$ ./sv
```

```
$ curl localhost:8888
Hello world!
$
```

but the script prints the following error:

```
$ ./sv
write(stdout): Broken pipe
$
```

I am running this script on Linux,
using GNU's implementation of `netcat` and coreutils.
I've tried running this script with both `dash` and `bash`; the same error occurs.

What is the cause of this error and how can I avoid it?

---

Edit: It seems that the error was caused
by leaving out the `read` command in `respond`
in simplifying my code for this question.
That or the lack of a `Connection: close` header
when testing with a web browser causes this error message.

Answer (score 2):

You're writing to the FIFO "tube" but no one is reading from it. You can try like this:

```
{ respond; cat tube > /dev/null; } | netcat -l -p 8888 > tube
```

I don't get the point of using the FIFO here. The following would just work:

```
respond | netcat -l -p 8888 > /dev/null
```

Comment: Sorry, I simplified the example in my question too much, leaving out some crucial details.  I need `respond` to read the request from stdin, which is connected to the stdout of `netcat` by the FIFO.  I have updated my question, and adding the `read` back seems to have fixed the error.  Thanks for your answer!